# How to run wire to new addition through attic roof?

Tags: electrical, wiring

We have an older house with a "sunroom" addition. This addition stays much warmer than the rest of the house, it has the longest AC duct run, and the room is almost all windows. The attic space is also hotter than the rest of the attic. The addition has higher ceilings than the rest of the house, with almost no attic, just about 6 or 8 inches between the roof and the ceiling, with no insulation there.

There are two existing attic fans in the original part of the house. However, they are disconnected, with no prior electrical line in site.

To get ready for summer, my plan is to run new wire to the existing fans (and see if they work, and maybe replace them ...) and install a new attic roof fan over the addition, which will also require running wire through the attic. We replaced the circuit breaker when we moved in a couple years ago, so there's plenty of space to add a new circuit.

The addition has a roof that was extended back onto the old house, creating a tiny attic space. There's about a 2 foot square hole cut in the old roof to access the new addition attic. Here's what it looks like. (the roof is angled like a normal house, but hard to show from the side).

[image: img]

I haven't bought a new fan yet, but it looks like there is space in the new addition attic, per manufacture guidelines for the fan I was looking at.

My question is **how to run the electrical lines safely / per code (United States) from the old attic to the new area**? I don't know if it's alright to just run the wire through the access hole or if it needs to be run some other way (conduit? a separate hole? idk). It's  hard to draw in the 2d picture, but my current plan is to run it to the edge and then up the old roof, through the access hole, turn 120 degrees to find the shortest path to the new addition roof, then run up to the spot to install the new fan.

(There is a ceiling fan in the addition, but I'm not sure where that's getting power from)

[image: img]

Here's a sketch of the other direction:

[image: img]

Comment: Addition roof is flat?

Comment: No, it's angled `^`. It's perpendicular to the original house, so the apex of the addition goes back over the original house until it meets the roof angle. I added a sketch looking head on.

Comment: Presuming you're using the caret (^) to indicate the shape of the roof, that would be termed "peaked".

Comment: So the addition basically has a vaulted ceiling, where the ceiling (drywall?) is attached to the rafters?